# Clang reject type_info as incomplete although <typeinfo> is included

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libstdc++

I'm lost as to why Clang rejects the following code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <exception>

const char* get_name( const std::exception_ptr eptr )
{
  return eptr.__cxa_exception_type()->name();
}

int main() {}
```

It OK with GCC, but Clang complains about `type_info` being an incomplete type:

```
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
$ clang++-3.2 -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
t.cc:6:37: error: member access into incomplete type 'const class type_info'
  return eptr.__cxa_exception_type()->name();
                                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/exception_ptr.h:144:19: note: forward declaration of
      'std::__exception_ptr::type_info'
      const class type_info*
                  ^
1 error generated.
$
```

**Question:** How do I fix it with Clang? Or am I missing something and Clang is right to reject the code?

Comment: You have problem not with `std::type_info` but with `std::__exception_ptr::type_info`, which seems like to be gcc-specific.

Comment: You're using non-standard functions, what do you expect?

Comment: I'm not using libc++, but libstdc++ (as you can see from the path in the error message). And the `std::__exception_ptr::type_info` is actually a wrongly created forward-declaration because Clang does not seem to pick up `std::type_info` as you can check in the header of the error message. And non-standard... well... the real world is not perfect. It's part of the code-base I am porting to Clang. I was just hoping for some constructive help.

Comment: Nope, Linux (Ubuntu 12.04, actually)

Comment: Try a preprocess and maybe that will tell you why type_info is not a complete type by the time you parse get_name().

Comment: I've removed my earlier comment, as it was mistaken.  However, I'm not sure about the correctness of mixing and matching one implementations headers with another compiler.  Some of the template code in g++ relies on internal g++ keywords (e.g. __is_final), which might not be present, or worse, might not have the same meaning, as g++.

Comment: From what I understand, Clang does support libstdc++ as well as libc++, see for example http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html point 7 from the top. Of course, this does not mean 100% compatibility, as evidenced by this question :)

Comment: @DaveS, how do you think people use Clang++ on platforms where libc++ doesn't work? Or how do you think they used it before libc++ _existed_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @HowardHinnant's comment, I managed to fix the problem. The problem became obvious in the preprocessor output: libstdc++ includes `<exception>` from `<type_info>` before it even *declared* `std::type_info`. That made Clang assume a new forward-declaration `std::__exception_ptr::type_info`. The solution is as simple as it is illegal:

```
namespace std { class type_info; }

#include <typeinfo>
#include <exception>

const char* get_name( const std::exception_ptr eptr )
{
  return eptr.__cxa_exception_type()->name();
}

int main() {}
```

Seems like I should check if libstdc++ already has a bug report for that and, if not, create one.

**UPDATE:** Bug [#56468](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56468) is now fixed for GCC 4.7.3+

Comment: @Xeo: I assume from your comment that g++ assumes that there is a type named `std::type_info` without a declaration?  Which answers my 'Why does this work g++' question nicely.

Comment: GCC just seems to implicitly declare `std::type_info`. You usually encounter this problem the first time when doing a typical Hello World with Clang and libstdc++.

Comment: Reported as bugzilla [#56468](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56468) against libstdc++.