# Build Mailcore2 for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mailcore2

I follow the [official build instractions](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/build-android) to recompile the library. In my case:

```
> export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
> export ANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_SDK/ndk-bundle
> ./build.sh
```

And get some errors during the compilation like:

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : MailCore <= MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp
In file included from /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../include/MailCore/MCObject.h:11:0,
                 from /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../include/MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h:5,
                 from /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../include/MailCore/MCBaseTypes.h:5,
                 from /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.h:13,
                 from /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp:9:
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp: In member function 'virtual void mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession::automaticConfigurationDone(mailcore::IMAPSession*)':
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp:874:87: warning: 'virtual mailcore::String* mailcore::IMAPSession::gmailUserDisplayName()' is deprecated (declared at /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/core/imap/MCIMAPSession.h:196) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY(String, mGmailUserDisplayName, session->gmailUserDisplayName());
                                                                                       ^
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../include/MailCore/MCUtils.h:8:27: note: in definition of macro 'MC_SAFE_COPY'
 #define MC_SAFE_COPY(o) ((o) != NULL ? (o)->copy() : NULL)
                           ^
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp:874:5: note: in expansion of macro 'MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY'
     MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY(String, mGmailUserDisplayName, session->gmailUserDisplayName());
     ^
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp:874:87: warning: 'virtual mailcore::String* mailcore::IMAPSession::gmailUserDisplayName()' is deprecated (declared at /Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/core/imap/MCIMAPSession.h:196) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY(String, mGmailUserDisplayName, session->gmailUserDisplayName());
                                                                                       ^
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../include/MailCore/MCUtils.h:8:41: note: in definition of macro 'MC_SAFE_COPY'
 #define MC_SAFE_COPY(o) ((o) != NULL ? (o)->copy() : NULL)
                                         ^
/Users/nikolay/Documents/Mailcore/mailcore2/build-android/jni/../../src/async/imap/MCIMAPAsyncSession.cpp:874:5: note: in expansion of macro 'MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY'
     MC_SAFE_REPLACE_COPY(String, mGmailUserDisplayName, session->gmailUserDisplayName());
     ^

... compiling goes ok...
... and again some errors...
```

And so on. Finally I get:

```
[arm64-v8a] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libMailCore.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libMailCore.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libMailCore.so
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:3: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Handler;
                 ^
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:4: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Looper;
                 ^
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:5: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
                   ^
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private Handler handler;
            ^
  symbol:   class Handler
  location: class MainThreadUtils
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                      ^
  symbol:   class Handler
  location: class MainThreadUtils
com/libmailcore/MainThreadUtils.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                              ^
  symbol:   variable Looper
  location: class MainThreadUtils
6 errors
1 warning
```

How can I recompile the library? In the end I want to fix a [text relocations error](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/1506) but it doesn't even make a clean build

Comment: where to add this:                                                                                                                           > export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
> export ANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_SDK/ndk-bundle
> ./build.sh                                                                                                                                         i am not able to make this setup. Please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's looking for Android platforms 16 and 21, and can't find them, that's why it shows the error message:

```
error: package android.os does not exist
```

These are usually installed in the folder `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms`

(Add this near the top of `build-android/build.sh`, to see what it's doing:

```
set -v
set -x
```

This will show the commands it's running, and the contents of shell variables.)

If you open the file `build-android/build.sh`, inside Mailcore2, you'll see lines like:

```
# Start building.
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
archs="armeabi armeabi-v7a x86"
```

Replace `android-16` with whatever version you have installed, or even better, install `android-16` because it's expecting that.
Also the `armeabi` platform support has been removed from the latest Android NDK, and it gives me errors about it. So remove `armeabi` and leave only `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`.

Also further down there is:

```
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21
archs="arm64-v8a"
```

and:

```
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
cd "$current_dir/../src/java"
...
```

**So it's easiest to install `android-16` and `android-21` to fix this issue.**

I was also getting the error:

```
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.
```

Finding this line:

```
$ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=$ANDROID_PLATFORM TARGET_ARCH_ABI=$TARGET_ARCH_ABI \
```

And adding `APP_PLATFORM` to it, like so, fixed that error:

```
$ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=$ANDROID_PLATFORM APP_PLATFORM=$ANDROID_PLATFORM TARGET_ARCH_ABI=$TARGET_ARCH_ABI \
```

I was also getting the error:

```
*** Android NDK: Invalid NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION value: 4.9. GCC is no longer supported. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md.    .  Stop.
```

Apparently GCC is no longer supported. I installed **clang**, and it proceeded to compile the project after that, but stopped on another error.

Additionally, I had to remove the line containing:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 \
```

as described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md).

I received the error:

```
MailCore2/build-android/jni/../../src/java/TypesUtils.cpp:84:32: error: member access into incomplete type 'const std::type_info'
MCLog("info name: %s", info->name());
                           ^
```

This is apparently related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098174/clang-reject-type-info-as-incomplete-although-typeinfo-is-included):

*GCC just seems to implicitly declare `std::type_info`. You usually encounter this problem the first time when doing a typical Hello World with Clang and libstdc++. – Xeo Feb 26 '13 at 20:42*

I wasn't able to resolve this issue yet, but I'll update this post when I get the chance.

Comment: Nice research! :)

Comment: @NikolayKulachenko Thanks, I'll try to finish it when I have some free time.